# How do I calculate a four colour gradient?

Tags: graphics, drawing, colors, gradient

If I have four colours (A, B, C & D) on four corners of a square and I want to fill that square with a gradient that blends nicely between the four colours how would I calculate the colour of the point E?

The closer E is to any of the other points, the strong that colour should affect the result.

Any idea how to do that? Speed and simplicity is preferred to accuracy.

[colours http://rabien.com/image/colours.png](http://rabien.com/image/colours.png)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The best solution when a gradient is required between two colors, is to use the [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) representation (Hue Saturation Value).

If you have the HSV values for your two colors, you just make linear interpolation for H, S and V, and you have nice colors (interpolation in RGB space always lead to "bad" results).

You also find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Conversion_from_RGB_to_HSL_or_HSV) the formulae to go from RGB to HSV and from HSV to RGB, respectively.

Now, for your problem with the four corner, you can make a linear combination of the four H/S/V values, weighted by the distance from E to that four points A,B,C and D.

EDIT: same method than tekBlues, but in HSV space (it is quite easy to test it in RGB and in HSV spaces. And you will see the differences. In HSV, you just turn around the chromatic cylinder, and this is why it gives nice result)

EDIT2: if you prefer "speed and simplicity", you may use a L1-norm, instead of a L2-norm (euclidian norm)

So, if `a` is the size of your square and the coordinate of your points are A(`0`,`0`), B(`0`,`a`), C(`a`,`0`), D(`a`,`a`), then the Hue of a point E(`x`,`y`) can be computed with:

```
Hue(E) = ( Hue(B)*y/a + Hue(A)*(1-y/a) ) * (x/a)  +  ( Hue(D)*y/a + Hue(C)*(1-y/a) ) * (1-x/a)
```

where `Hue(A)` is the Hue of point A, `Hue(B)` the Hue of B, etc...

You apply the same formulae for the Saturation and Value.

Once you have the Hue/Saturation/Value for your point E, you can transform it in RGB space.

Comment: I got it to work, thank you very much. Looks pretty good too!

Comment: The combination method above is also known as "bi-linear interpolation".  You are performing this separately on H, S, and V values.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this site, which gives a visual demo of @ThibThib's comment that "gradients in HSV will be more satifying":

http://www.perbang.dk/rgbgradient/

It is a gradient creator that will create and show BOTH an RGB gradient and an HSV gradient.

If you try 9 steps from FFAAAA to AAFFAA (light red to green), you’ll get a nice transition through light yellow, and the HSV and RGB ones look similar.

But try 9 steps from FF0000 to 00FF00 (bold red to green), and you’ll see the RGB one transition through a yucky greenish brown.  The HSV gradient, however, transitions through bold yellow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Determine the distance of point E to each point A,B,C,D
2. The color for point E will be the combination of Red / Green / Blue. Calculate each color axis as the average of the same color axis for A,B,C,D, ponderating by distance.

   distance_a = sqrt((xa-xe)^2+(ya-ye)^2)

   distance_b = ....

   sum_distances = distance_a + distance_b ...

   red = (red_a*distance_a + red_b*distance_b ... ) / sum_distances

   color_E = ColorFromARgb(red,green,blue)

Comment: Something is wrong with this approach, I fear.  The "weight" for how much "A" contributes to the color for "E" should be proportional to the *inverse* of the distance.  As written above, if E is right at A, then the distance to A is 0, and therefore A will contribute *nothing* to the value of E.  But that is the very case where ONLY A should contribute to E.