# different colors for different values from 0 value (apply black) to infinity value (apply white)

Tags: html, css, colors, formula, rgb

I want to display different colors for different numbers that are random from 0 to infinity.
I've reached it for color that are gray (from black to white). I want to colorize it in some way.

So, my formula for gray is simple:

The bigger number - the color is closer to white.

Here is the formula that work in this case:
Lets's N is a number.
`color3=colo2=color1=Math.floor(255/(1+N));` //always between 0 and 255, right?

The bigger N - the closer to 255. And it works.

Then I use  "rgb(color1, color2, color3)"; to apply this color.
Looks well.

However, I want to display not gray in between black and white, but blue, green, red, yellow etc in between instead. So it looks smoothly and colorized, and the formula for calculating rgb colors looks easy.

Added:
As result, my formula helps to walk from black to white by diagonal on the RGB cube, but I want it to be less "straight".
[image]

Comment: If you're not picky about exactly which colors in your gradient, check out the HSV interpolation in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106959/how-do-i-calculate-a-four-colour-gradient).

Comment: That's because any option is fine. 4 colors is fine, 16 colors is fine. Any.

Comment: What you describe is likely to look awful. What is your use-case for this, so someone can suggest a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier of you used 3 different random numbers:

e.g. A, B and C are randomly generated.

```
color1=Math.floor(255/(1+A));
color2=Math.floor(255/(1+B));
color3=Math.floor(255/(1+C));
```

"rgb(color1, color2, color3)";