# Generate hex numbers based on percentage

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a way to generate a gradual hexadecimal color based on a percentage with Ruby.

```
0% = #6da94a
50% = #decc30
100% = #ce2d4a
```

Then programmatically generate the hexadecimal values in between those.

So I might have something like `percent_to_hex(10)` and that would spit out whatever hexadecimal value is 10% along the gradual gradient between 0% (green) and 50% (yellow).

Comment: What have you tried?  This doesn't seem like a Ruby problem.  More like a color theory problem.  [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106959/how-do-i-calculate-a-four-colour-gradient).

Comment: I would try a cross-multiplication first...

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a small mistake in tralston's answer.

```
(x + percent * 100 * (y - x)).round
```

should be changed to:

```
(x + percent / 100.0 * (y - x)).round
```

Also `i.to_s(16)` would be a problem if you have 0 (255), as you can get a result like "ff0ff". I would recommend using `"%02x" % i` instead.

Here is the complete example:

```
def percent_to_hex(percent, start, stop)
  colors = [start,stop].map do |c|
    c.scan(/../).map { |s| s.to_i(16) }
  end

  colors_int = colors.transpose.map do |x,y|
    (x + percent / 100.0 * (y - x)).round
  end

  colors_int.map { |i| "%02x" % i }.join("")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very polished method, but here's a good start:

```
# Example input: percent_to_hex(25, "abcdef", "ffffff") => "c0daf3"
def percent_to_hex(percent, start, stop)
  colors = [start,stop].map do |c|
    c.scan(/../).map { |s| s.to_i(16) }
  end

  colors_int = colors.transpose.map do |x,y|
    (x + percent * 100 * (y - x)).round
  end

  colors_int.map { |i| i.to_s(16) }.join("")
end
```

Of course if you could customize it further to add or remove the leading "#" of the hex color code, etc.